# Magento can't load some resource files (images, css and js)

Tags: magento, url, path

I have a magento site in: [www.petitebox.com.br](http://www.petitebox.com.br) which, all of the sudden, began to mess all the design up. Magento can't load some resources files (some images, css and js), even the backend is ruined. You can see in image [here](http://screencast.com/t/wa5sDDzIwgN).

Does anyone know if it's more a problem in .htaccess or in Magento Settings? Or maybe anything else? How can I fix it?

### EDIT

Magento can't load only some of the files. Another group of files, Magento can load without problems: [image here](http://screencast.com/t/0jiCWmmdCwMj)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try changing permissions to /var and /media folders, it has to be 0775 permission. Then delete the cache manually through your command line:
rm -rf /yoursite/var/cache/mage--*
(Be careful with this one).

Check your core_config_data configuration:

```
select * from core_config_data where path like '%web/secure/base_url%';

select * from core_config_data where path like '%web/unsecure/base_url%';
```

They have to be like your url, if are different, try with:

```
update core_config_data set value='http://www.petitebox.com.br/' where path like '%web/secure/base_url%';

update core_config_data set value='http://www.petitebox.com.br/' where path like '%web/unsecure/base_url%';
```

I think with this it would be enough.

Greetings

Comment: ¿Did you make the changes recursively? $ chmod -R 0775 media/

Comment: Yep.. some resources is loading without problems. Maybe it's some path settings that I have to change directly on the database?

Comment: I see some /data/ in your url resources.

Comment: Yes but why would Magento use /data/ for some files and for the other part it doesn't use?

Comment: I never seen it something like that. Is all I can do. I hope it helps
Greetings.

Comment: Maybe a layout is changing the routes of the js.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35316/discussion-between-beto-castillo-and-rodrigo-alves)

Answer (score 0):

I logged onto your site and found this issue, due to incorrect settings somewhere it is trying to fetch the following URL:

```
http://www.petitebox.com.br/data/baby-br/baby-live/skin/frontend/baby/default/css/main_default.css
```

The correct URL is:

```
http://www.petitebox.com.br/skin/frontend/baby/default/css/main_default.css
```

I would do 2 things:

1. Search for `data/baby-br/baby-live` in your source code - remove it where it is not needed.
2. Search for `data/baby-br/baby-live` in your database - remove it where it is not needed.